# Create XML Structure from XML Column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xsd

I have a table with more then 1 Million rows. In this table I have a column with large XML Files (DataType XML). Now I have to generate / find out the structure of all these XML File.

The structure of the XML Files are usually different - So its not always the same. Is there a possibility to generate ie. a XSD File for all these rows to find out the structure or to evaluate the tags inside the xml file ?

Do you have any idea / process to get the structure of all these xml files ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no generic way, at least none that I know...
Just imagine two XMLs, which look the same, but one has a child element which is missing in the other one. This might be the same schema, or not...

With an approach like the following you can retrieve some *meta-data*. Write this into a side table and try to use `GROUP BY` to find your *XML families*

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, ShortDescr VARCHAR(100), YourXML XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('root and test', N'<root><test/></root>')
,('root and test and more', N'<root><test/><a /><b /></root>')
,('blah and test', N'<blah><test/></blah>')
,('no root (blah and blub)', N'<blah></blah><blub />')
,('no content', NULL)
;

SELECT t.ID
      ,t.ShortDescr
      ,CASE ISNULL(t.YourXML.value('count(/*)','int'),0)
            WHEN 1 THEN 'HasRoot'
            WHEN 0 THEN 'empty'
            ELSE 'Fragment' END AS XmlFormat
      ,t.YourXML.value('local-name((/*)[1])','nvarchar(max)') AS RootName 
      ,t.YourXML.value('local-name((/*[1]/*)[1])','nvarchar(max)') AS FirstChild
FROM @tbl t;
```

The result for this:

```
+----+-------------------------+-----------+----------+------------+
| ID | ShortDescr              | XmlFormat | RootName | FirstChild |
+----+-------------------------+-----------+----------+------------+
| 1  | root and test           | HasRoot   | root     | test       |
+----+-------------------------+-----------+----------+------------+
| 2  | root and test and more  | HasRoot   | root     | test       |
+----+-------------------------+-----------+----------+------------+
| 3  | blah and test           | HasRoot   | blah     | test       |
+----+-------------------------+-----------+----------+------------+
| 4  | no root (blah and blub) | Fragment  | blah     |            |
+----+-------------------------+-----------+----------+------------+
| 5  | no content              | empty     | NULL     | NULL       |
+----+-------------------------+-----------+----------+------------+
```